# Retrieving values only once without using ItemDataBoundEvent which repeatedly return the value

Tags: ajax, datalist, itemdatabound

On DataService.cs, the function returns a list as follows:

```
[WebMethod()]
public SomeList[] GetListing(
```

On client side, I have this:

```
        function onListLoadSuccess(someLists) {            

            var dataList = $find('<%= DataList1.ClientID %>');
            dataList.set_dataSource(someLists);
            dataList.dataBind();
```

Then when it is bound to DataList1:

```
        function onListItemDataBound(sender, e) {

            var item = e.get_item();
            if (item.get_isDataItemType()) {

                var someList = item.get_dataItem();
                alert(someList.Country);
                alert(someList.City);
```

My issue is I only need to retrieve Country and City once, I wonder how I can retrieve those values without using **onListItemDataBound** function which repeatedly return the value until all the rows has been run through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work now.. silly me!

```
        function onListLoadSuccess(someLists) {  
            alert(someLists[0].City);
            alert(someLists[0].Country);
```